# cordova android spalsh screen faddes off quickly

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, eclipse-mars

I am creating an android application using apache cordova and building and running the application using eclipse mars. The problem is that the spalsh screen fades off too quickly. I want it to stay for 3000 seconds and then start fading whereas it  starts fading from the start. also trying to set fading off but no luck. Heres my config file. Please help

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.eximapp7" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Useful Addresses</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <feature name="SocialSharing">
            <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
        </feature>
        <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />  
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.1.1" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set splash screen delay to 6 seconds

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000" />
```